# Angular SharePoint Request Digest

Tags: angular, typescript, sharepoint

I am building an angular application that is running within SharePoint and I would like to know if there is a way to refresh the Request Digest. I looked into https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs but I don't find anything that will allow me to refresh the Request Digest token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use rest api Call on "/_api/contextinfo" get refresh the Request Digest token
data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue